# redirect from php to another file not happening

Tags: javascript, php

When I run the php code I was not able to go to the other page. 
Here is the php snippet...

```
 }
       if (headers_sent()) {
           die("Redirect failed. Please click on this link: <a href=...>");
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <!-- Script to redirect to other url...-->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.location.href = 'http://<?php echo  
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":8001/".$url ?>';
        </script>
    <?php
        ob_end_flush();
        exit();
    ?>
    ...
```

Firebug output:

Response

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8001
        /pall_oneless.php?uid=6fe9b73027';
    </script>
```

Response headers as shown in Firebug:

> Connection 
>      close
>      Content-Type
>      text/html
>      Host
>      localhost:8001
>      X-Powered-By
>      PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
>      view source
>      Accept 
>      text/html, */*; q=0.01
>      Accept-Encoding
>      gzip, deflate
>      Accept-Language
>      en-US,en;q=0.5
>      Connection 
>      keep-alive
>      Content-Length 
>      91
>      Content-Type
>      application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>      Cookie 
>      PHPSESSID=fnckn52eoai0dqdmdutsd3ljm6
>      Host
>      localhost:8001
>      Referer
>      http://localhost:8001/login.php
>      User-Agent 
>      Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
>      X-Requested-With
>      XMLHttpRequest
>      x-insight
>      activate

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do there is redirect, there is no need to user JavaScript. Use headers and it will be even faster: change your `else` clause to

```
else{
    $newLocation = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':8001/'.$url;
    header("Location: $newLocation");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you do a redirect in php. That's in javascript.
In php you do:

```
...
else {
   header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':8001/'.$url);
   exit;
}
```